# Programmatically create a ContentDatabase C# SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, event-receivers, content-database, c-sharp

I am searching for a solution of my problem. I banged my head for the last few hours and tried several things and solutions found on google or stack-exchange.

The database should be created via `Event Receiver`. I know that elevated prev impersonate as the app pool account which has not enough rights to create a database. But even as a farm admin on my development machine (there is only one account for all services, app pools and so on) I run into an access denied (with the super admin itself :-D )

I don´t know how to go on. Is it possible to SQL authentication and use a SQL user in some way? I tried this way on my development machine with the sa user and the right password BUT `access denied.`

Due to the fact that this should be a self service solution timer jobs are no solution for me :-( WebService and farm application page are not the best way from my point of view.

Comment: where it is getting access denied...on SQL server or on the sharepoint server? can you share the error details and code as well...if possible share screen shot

Comment: getting the error while debugging my solution in VS2013. The error says that the server is not available (but it is, checked with UDL file) or the user has not enough rights (if I use the AD account) or is says directly access denied while using the sa account from SQL. But when I check the connection to the SQL server with the UDL file, there is no access denied with the sa account.

Comment: It´s an exception, no SqlExcetion. But I assume that the access denied comes from the SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens from time to time, in the server OM, there's a check against the context (Web or not) so some operations are forbidden even if the identity running the code has the correct permissions.

You don' want to consider a timer job, but in your case I would think again: with a timer job you'd have no problem at all.
That job could be a [work item job](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/processing-items-work-item-timer-jobs-sharepoint-2010/), and run every x minutes (even with x=1) to check the queue of work item. If nothing in the queue, it does nothing, thus consummes no resources. If there's a work item, it creates the DB (which is by the way a very long operation, so the x minutes delay the job adds may not be a problem).

I would really consider that approach, since it frees you from permissions/Web contexts problem, avoid potential security holes, and prevent you from running a very long operation from the ER/Web context.

Comment: Well, maybe I need to overthink... But there is no way to use a SQL user to add/create a new database through an ER?

Comment: Yes, probably... but do you know how to create that new content DB? What settings. What permissions? And most importantly, what schema? Anyway, this will be completely not supported. And definitely not falling into the philisophy of ER and Web contexts...

Comment: If these points are coming up I prefer the workitem TJ ^^

Comment: Wise decision :) In your position, I would surely go with the work item job!

Comment: There is only one point left. In the productive environment the solution is a self service application and I need to check whether there is already a workItem for the creating a cdb for the specific web application. But I think this is possible, isn´t it?

Comment: Yup, you can review existing work items through `SPWorkItemCollection`. If the whole work item job infrastructure does not suit you, you can also implement your own technical list in SP, and use it as the queue for scheduled tasks. Uou can easily tailor a custom SP list to fit exactly your needs. The only "problem" is to store this list in a convenient location, like the root of the site collection. Each time the (normal) timer job runs, it will check that list, and update items with a status ("processed", "failed'...).

Comment: I wrote a work item timer job. Unfortunately the job does not appear in the CA (Timer Job Definitions). After debugging my code there is no error while registering the timer job with a webApp feature. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: To protocol: it´s not my first TJ ^^

Comment: Work item jobs behave as standard timer jobs... You should see it in CA, Nothing special there.

Answer (score 0):

This thing is driving me crazy so I need to ask a few questions.

This is how I "create" the job:

```
CreateDBWorkItemTimerJob job = new CreateDBWorkItemTimerJob(JobName, webApp);

SPMinuteSchedule schedule = new SPMinuteSchedule();

schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
schedule.Interval = 1;
schedule.EndSecond = 59;

job.Schedule = schedule;
job.Update();
```

based on that:

```
public CreateDBWorkItemTimerJob(string name, SPWebApplication webApplication)
            : base(name, webApplication, null, SPJobLockType.None)
        {
            this.Title = "Create new ContentDB for WebApplication";
        }
```

No error but still no job in the job list. What´s wrong? I also tried to use it with a SPOneTimeSchedule - no luck.